# Disable $OKButton until textbox is populated?

Tags: powershell, textbox

I have a question on an event trigger. I'd like to have my OKButton be disabled until a textbox(s) are populated, pretty much requiring the user to input data into that field or cancel out of the form. I have `$OKButton.enabled = $false` already and think I need something along the lines of

```
if ($Textbox3.Text.Length <1) {
    $OKButton.enabled = $true
} else {
    $OKButton.enabled = $false
}
```

I have this piece of code in my script currently and the OK button is disabled but I think I am having a syntax error because when Textbox3 is filled the button remains disabled.

Comment: `$Textbox3.Text.Length -lt 1`

Comment: Thank you Mathias that worked

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, the "less-than" comparison operator is not `<` but rather `-lt` (short for, you guessed it, ***l***ess **t**han):

```
if ($Textbox3.Text.Length -lt 1) {
    $OKButton.enabled = $true
} else {
    $OKButton.enabled = $false
}
```

Read more about comparison operators in PowerShell with [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx)